# How to save the output of text from selenium chrome (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium for extracting comments of Youtube. 
Everything went well. But when I print comment.text, the output is the last sentence. 
I don't know who to save it for further analyze (cleaning and tokenization)

```
 path = "/mnt/c/Users/xxx/chromedriver.exe"
```

> This is the path that I saved and  downloaded my chrome

```
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(path)
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPni755-Krg"
chrome.get(url)
chrome.maximize_window()
```

> scrolldown

```
sleep = 5
chrome.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, 500);'

time.sleep(sleep)

chrome.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, 1080);')
time.sleep(sleep)

text_comment = chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contents"]')
comments = text_comment.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')
comment_ids = []
```

> Try this approach for getting the text of all comments. (the forloop part edited- there was no indention in the previous code.)

```
for comment in comments:
    comment_ids.append(comment.get_attribute('id'))

    print(comment.text)
```

> when I print, i can see all the texts here. but how can i open it for further study. Should i always use for loop? I want to tokenize the texts but the output is only last sentence. Is there a way to save this .text file with the whole texts inside it and open it again? I googled it a lot but it wasn't successful.

Comment: In your loop, you are appending strings to comment_ids, is the print statement in the loop? If it is not, when you ask to print 'comment' it might still be set to the last comment in comments

Comment: there was a typo, I corrected it here. no the issue is not related to that. I want to use the output of print(comment.text) later. But i don't know how to save all the texts in comment.text . Yes you're right, outside the for loop, the output will be only the last sentence. but I want to save  all the texts for further study.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you're just trying to store these comments to reference later. Your current solution is to append them to a string and use a token to create substrings? I'm not familiar with pythons data structures, but this sounds like a great job for an array or a list depending on how you plan to reference this data.